# SqlConnection Not Reading

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a SQL Command that query's a DB table and retrieves information....very basic.

I can see the reader has the results from the DB table when debugging, but for some reason it always skips on "While Reader.Read" and then skips down and closes the connection never reading the data.

```
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("lbx_EmailDomains_SELECT", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
           // Never Reaches Here
        }
    }

    reader.Close();
    con.Close();
```

**UPDATE: Removing the reader.HasRows fixed the issue.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that actually it's not getting as far as `reader.Read()`. I suspect that `reader.HasRows` is returning false, precisely because you haven't called `reader.Read()` yet.

I don't think the test for `HasRows` is useful at all, to be honest - I'd just get rid of it.

Note that it would be better to use `using` statements and get rid of the manual `Close()` calls, so that the connection/reader will be closed even in the event of an exception.

EDIT: According to the comments:

- It *should* work, and this pattern is shown in some MSDN documentation
- `HasRows` was apparently returning `true` before `reader.Read()` returned false
- Removing the `HasRows` test apparently fixed the problem. Odd.

I wonder whether there's some debugger interaction we don't know about here...

Comment: When i debug and it reaches the read.HasRows, it's returned as true and continues on to While Reader.Read. that is where its stopped and gets skipped.

Comment: @thesandman: That sounds surprising and illogical to me - if you get rid of the `HasRows` test entirely, does that help? I wonder whether `HasRows` is *implicitly* calling `Read`, or something like that...

Comment: It's odd logic, but it should still work.  There are a number of examples on MSDN's site that use this same flow.  Here is one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Perhaps you're screwing up the state of your reader by looking at it under the debugger?  If you follow Jon's suggestion (getting rid of the HasRows test) and then let it run without messing with anything in the Watch or Immediate windows, does it run?

Comment: There needs to be a term for this in computer science - A bug created by the very act of trying to debug itself.

Comment: @Mike. Given it seem s to be the inverse of a Heisenbug, perhaps a we should call it a Schrodingbug. :D